# clever way to reduce if-elseif statements

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, control-flow

I've developing a code to restrict SpinBox to letters instead of integers. Everything is working fine but I would like to reduce the if-elseif statements if there is any clever way. This is the code

```
std::string AlphaSpinBox::textFromValue(int value) 
{
    // I feel the code is Ok but willing to change it if there is a better way.
    // value is restricted [0-25] inclusive. 
    std::string str("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    return std::string(str[value]);
}

int AlphaSpinBox::valueFromText(std::string &text) 
{
    // can I shorten the following?!
    // text is solely one letter (i.e. either upper or lower)
    if(text == 'A' || text == 'a')
        return 0;
    else if(text == 'B' || text == 'b' )
        return 1;
    else if(text == 'C' || text == 'c')
        return 2;
    else if(text == 'D' || text == 'd')
        return 3;
    ... to z letter
}
```

Comment: You could consider `std::tolower`. Note that for the C library function the argument must not be negative (except EOF). So in practice, cast the argument to `unsigned char`, to avoid Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Might help: http://www.asciitable.com/ (I doubt it's the best way though.)

Comment: `int valueFromText( std::string& text ) { std::string str( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ); return str.find(std::toupper( text[0]) ); }` If its reasonable for you to assume that your character set will always have contiguous and ordered alpha characters, you can also just return the char - first alpha char.

Comment: `if(text == 'A' || text == 'a')` can't compile, because you are comparing a `std::string` with a single `char`. **If it were of `char` type**, and **guaranteed** to be in range a-z, or A-Z, one could use simple `return std::toupper(text) - 'A';`.

Comment: you may dig into something like `return toUpper(text)[0] - 0x41`

Comment: @truf Please explain how magic constants (like `0x41`) are superior to simple `'A'`?

Comment: `std::stoi(text, 0, 36)`

Comment: You could prepopulate a lookup table and then say `return table[text]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about:

```
 if (text.size()>0 && std::isalpha(text[0]))
     return std::toupper(text[0])-'A'; 
 else return -1;    // or throw an exception
```

Here an [online demo](https://ideone.com/hzissG).

How it works:  It first checks if the string is not empty and if the first char is a letter [(with `isalpha()`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha).  If it's valid, as you make no difference between lowercase and uppercase, we convert the char [`toupper()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper).  As your return values are sequential in the order of the letter, we just have to substract the first letter.

Comment: This might not work with all character sets like EBCDIC

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed, the assumption is that the capital letters are sequential, which is the case for ASCII, unicode, ISO 8859, Windows 125x, and most of the other [common schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings).  It's not the case of EBCDIC, which is to my knowledge the only set where A-Z are not in sequential order.  Fortunately it's not all too common nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

Each letter has an integer value according to the ASCII table. If you look that up, you will also find that the letters were conveniently placed in the table: a to z all follow each other directly, same for A to Z.

You can first determine lowercase or uppercase and then return `text[0] - 'a'`, or `text[0] - 'b'`.

Comment: The OP didn't say that ASCII was guaranteed.

Comment: @KerrekSB Using EBCDIC is the sort of thing questioners tend to mention up-front.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate multiple `if` statements in your `valueFromText` function by  utilizing the string's [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) member function and changing the function signature slightly:

```
int valueFromText(const std::string& s, char c) {
    return s.find(std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing a small class or struct with a static member(`std::map` - `look up table`) & some static methods that acts as a wrapper would most definitely work in your situation. The use of the code is fairly clean, readable, easy to use, should be portable and reusable.

---

**Note:** *- This will work as is provided that the system's character codes are sequentially defined; otherwise, you will need some other mechanism to `initialize` the static map.*

---

**AlphaSpinBox.h**

```
#ifndef ALPHA_SPIN_BOX_H
#define ALPHA_SPIN_BOX_H

#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>

struct AlphaSpinBox {    
    // static table
    static std::map<unsigned, std::string> table_;    
    // Must be called first
    static void initializeMap();    
    // helper function
    static std::string toUpper( const std::string& str );    
    // get string from value
    static std::string textFromValue( const unsigned& val );        
    // get value from string
    static unsigned valueFromText( const std::string& text );

    // other member's, functions etc. that you may have for this class
};

#endif // !ALPHA_SPIN_BOX_H
```

---

**AlphaSpinBox.cpp**

```
#include "AlphaSpinBox.h"

// define static member
std::map<unsigned, std::string> AlphaSpinBox::table_;

void AlphaSpinBox::initializeMap() {
    // Could do some checks here to see if this function has not been called
    // then display a message to the user that this function needs to be called first;
    // and to check if it has already been called once before; warning the user
    // that this method should only initialize the map once per application run.
    static char c = 'A';
    static std::string str;
    for ( unsigned n = 0; n < 26; n++ ) {
        str.assign( &c );
        table_.insert( std::make_pair( n, str ) );
        c++;
    }
}

std::string AlphaSpinBox::toUpper( const std::string& str ) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::toupper );
    return result;
}

std::string AlphaSpinBox::textFromValue( const unsigned& val ) {
    // you could check to see if val is within range before returning...
    return table_[val];
}

unsigned AlphaSpinBox::valueFromText( const std::string& text ) {
    std::string upper = toUpper( text );
    for ( auto pair : table_ ) {
        if ( upper == pair.second ) {
            return pair.first;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "AlphaSpinBox.h"

int main() {

    // Must Be Called First
    AlphaSpinBox::initializeMap();

    // Remember that the map first entry's key starts at 0 and not 1
    std::cout << "The number 8 has letter: " 
              << AlphaSpinBox::textFromValue( 8 ) 
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The letter Q has value: " 
              << AlphaSpinBox::valueFromText( std::string( "Q" ) ) 
              << std::endl;

    // check case for lower cases being converted to upper case
    std::cout << "The letter j has value: " 
              << AlphaSpinBox::valueFromText( std::string( "j" ) ) 
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char q;
    std::cin >> q;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is, maybe, more understandable one:

```
int AlphaToNumeric(string &value)
{
    return (value.front() >= 'A' && value.front() <= 'Z') ? value.front() - 'A' : (value.front() >= 'a' && value.front() <= 'z') ? value.front() - 'a' : -1;
}
```

Or:

```
int AlphaToNumeric(string &value)
{
    return (value.front() >= 65 && value.front() <= 90) ? value.front() - 65 : (value.front() >= 97 && value.front() <= 122) ? value.front() - 97 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this qualifiers as "clever", but assuming you only want to look at the first character of `text`, you can simply do

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int AlphaSpinBox::valueFromText(const std::string &text) 
{
     std::string str("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
     int retval = -2;
     if (text.size() > 0)
     {
         char c = std::toupper(text[0]);
         std::size_t index = str.find(c);
         retval = (index != std::string::npos) ? int(index) : -1;
     }
     return retval;
}
```

Unlike the code in the original question, this will compile (since it attempts to convert the first character in the string, not the whole string).  However, it also does more checks, so will return `-2` if given a zero length string, `-1` if the first character in the string is not alphabetic.

If you ASSUME a character set in which (uppercase) letters occur sequentially, this can be made much simpler.  This assumption is not strictly true for all standardised character sets, but is true more often than not with modern systems.

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int AlphaSpinBox::valueFromText(const std::string &text) 
{
     int retval = -2;
     if (text.size() > 0)
     {
         int c = std::toupper(text[0]);
         retval = std::isupper(c) ? c - 'A' : -1;
     }
     return retval;
}
```

The choice to use one of these versions or the other depends on level of confidence that the code will never be ported to a system with a character set in which letters are non-sequential.